# What phrasing can be used to denote the 'placing' of stakeholders on a scale with two opposing groups

Tags: phrase-requests

I'm helping my girlfriend with her thesis, and we're trying to come up with a compact, specific phrasing for this question.

To explain, in her field, there are two opposing groups, groups that support 'commitment to AAA', and groups that support 'commitment to BBB'.
Part of her thesis was to do research among the stakeholders, to find out how they think about XXX, and conclude if they support commitment to AAA or commitment to BBB.

So far, we've come up with:

> "How do stakeholders **position** XXX **on the topic of** commitment to AAA **as opposed to** commitment to BBB?"

Basically, we came up with this by thinking of a scale, with AAA on the left, and BBB on the right, and then determining the position of the stakeholders. However, we don't really like 'on the topic of', as it's too vague or general for these oposing groups.
We're not sure about the bold parts, and we're very open to suggestions.

Comment: @lbf I'm sorry, I'm not sure if I understand what you mean with 'brownie points'

Comment: points one gains with a person they are helping ( your gf!)

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. Are you saying that you want to compare the position that supporters of AAA have on XXX to the position that supporters of BBB have on XXX?

Comment: So, let's say that 10 people support AAA and 5 people support BBB. On a scale where 100% for AAA is -10 and 100% support for BBB is +10, this would put the overall group's belief at -3.3? (Assuming I have the math right.) If so, I think your use of XXX is confusing the statement. Perhaps: *How do the stakeholders collectively position themselves on a relative scale between AAA and BBB?*

Comment: @JasonBassford, the XXX is very important, as that is the practice that is being evaluated. My girlfriend is asking the stakeholders how they feel about XXX, and then uses the responses to see how the stakeholders are positioned in AAA vs BBB.

Comment: @Acccumulation, no that is not what I'm asking. I want to determine the position of the stakeholders, and place them on a 'scale' of AAA vs BBB

Comment: @ROIMaison Ah. Okay, so: *How do stakeholders collectively position XXX on a relative scale between AAA and BBB?*

Comment: That doesn't make sense.  A position isn't a number.

Comment: @Acccumulation, hence the accents around 'scale'. There are two opposing groups, and the research is focused on finding out where the stakeholders are relative to these two groups

Comment: *Position* and *stand* seem the right words here. "How do stakeholders **position themselves** on the topic of commitment to AAA as opposed to commitment to BBB?" ; "How do stakeholders **take a stand** on the topic of commitment to AAA as opposed to commitment to BBB?"

Answer (score 1):

How **heavily** do stakeholders **weigh** XXX when considering a predisposition for either AAA or BBB?

[Heavily](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/heavily) - adverb - To a great degree

[Weigh](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/weigh) - verb - Assess the nature or importance of, especially with a view to a decision or action.